# Cannot load static files in django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I added the following lines in my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
```

Then I edited my HTML file to use `{% load static %}` and `<img src="{% static 'static/myapp/images/ABC.png' %}" alt="">`,  but still I am not able to see the ABC.png pic on my webpage. Can someone please help?

Screenshots of .py files:
[image: Screenshots of .py files]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issus is that you are incorrectly requesting the asset, use `{% static 'myapp/images/ABC.png' %}` instead. I suppose that you have the following structure in your app:

```
myapp
   static
      myapp
         images
            ABC.png
   templetes
   views.py
   ...
```

As you can see, is not necessary to add the name of your statics directory. The path is relative to the static folder of any of your apps in your project.

Comment: Static is not inside the myapp it is outside. and this solution is not working

Comment: Just using `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` should work. You should have the static folder inside your apps instead your project, you can have one static folder by each app and  the path you use in the templates is relative to your static folders. try running `python manage.py collectstatic`